# In App purchase details- New version : Status- Waiting for upload

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am facing an issue regarding the In App purchase. I had launched my app v1.0 before with In-App purchase. Now i uploaded the v1.1 with In-App purchase. The app is showing "Waiting for Review" status. But the In-App purchase is still showing "Waiting for upload". What is this kind of issue. How can i resolve this. Please help.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First reject the old binary. Then delete the in app purchase newer version and then re-upload the binary.

Answer (score 2):

Do not need rejection of binary and deleting of all in-App-Purchase..

"Waiting for Upload" because you preferred to share your content with Apple (you maybe chose it or missed it).

On the screen, where is written "Waiting for Upload", there is two button [edit] [delete].
Just delete new version of in-App-Purchase.

It is not necessary to add new version of IAP, you can just edit it!!!

Regards :)
loydspace@gmail.com if any questions contact